# What is going wrong with this query?

Tags: php, postgresql

```php
public function get_modno_sno($id) 
{   
    $query = 'select  a.model_no,a.serial_no,a.stock_id from tra_item_stock a where a.trans_id is  NULL and a.model_no = '.$id.'
    union
    select  a.model_no,a.serial_no,a.stock_id from tra_indent_issue_details_2 a where a.flag = 3 and a.model_no ='.$id;
    $result = $this->db->query($query);
    return $result->result();
}
```

When I run this query error displayed as:

> column "kb234" does not exist

`kb234` is character varying value passed to `$id`

Comment: What is the Data type of `model_no ` ?

Comment: hey you missed `'` here `a.model_no ='.$id;`(in the second select )

Comment: @vivek it is character varying

Comment: I know SQL but not postgres, but isn't your `and a.model_no ='.$id;` missing a closing ' ?

Comment: Please don't deploy code like that: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @idstam Thanks for valuable tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not surround `kb234` with quotes, so the database identifies it as a column name.

You could modify you code to include the quotes:

```
public function get_modno_sno($id) 
    {   
        $query = "select  a.model_no,a.serial_no,a.stock_id from tra_item_stock a where a.trans_id is  NULL and a.model_no = '$id'
        union
        select  a.model_no,a.serial_no,a.stock_id from tra_indent_issue_details_2 a where a.flag = 3 and a.model_no = '$id'";
        $result = $this->db->query($query);
        return $result->result();
    }
```

Note, however, that creating SQL queries by using string manipulation is a dodgy practice, that leaves your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should consider using a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php).

Answer (score 2):

```
.model_no ='.$id;
```

is missing an ' at the end for the union query